# Is there any existing human urdf model?

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to use a human model in gazebo. Is there any Is there any existing human urdf model? I tried with [this one](http://code.google.com/p/metu-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/kadir/affordance_learning/al_robots/defs/human.urdf.xacro?r=48). However, it only show [image: image description]

I am wondering if there is any other effective human urdf model?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69361/is-there-any-existing-human-urdf-model?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Gazebo 1.0 you could insert human models through the insert tab. Perphaps that is still possible (don't now if they have all the urdf features)

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0